# Tensor classification

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

I have the following problem. I have a tensor $\Phi$ that is curvature like, i.e. satisfies the next properties:

(1) $\Phi(X,Y,Z,W) = −\Phi(Y,X,Z,W)$;

(2) $\Phi(X,Y,Z,W) + \Phi(W,X,Z,Y) + \Phi(Y,W,Z,X) = 0$;

(3) $\Phi(X,Y,Z,W) = − \Phi(X,Y,W,Z)$.

And there is an object defined by $S(X,Y)=\Phi(X,Y,X,Y)$ which has the property that if $\Phi$ is curvature like, then $S$ is symmetric, but opposite does not hold generally.

My question is, if we want to classify tensors according to the conditions, (a) $S$ is symmetric then $\Phi$ is curvature like, (b) $S$ is symmetric then $\Phi$ is not curvature like, what would be a starting point and does it make sense/ I had never try to do similar things, so good reference would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: The object $S$ defined by $S(X,Y) = \Phi(X,Y,X,Y)$ is not a tensor, because it's not linear in either of its arguments.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake, I will edit the question.